# How to get the value of this array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
router.post('/ingredients', (req, res) => {
   
var abc = [];

   var a = data.toString().split("\r\n");      
    var arr = a.toString().split(",");

    arr.forEach(function (i, e) {

      if (i != "\r" && i != "\n" && i != "" && i != " ")
      {
        var v = i.trim().toLowerCase();
       
          Ingredient.findOne({name: v}, (err, us) => {

            if(us)
            {          
              var rr = {
                name: us.name,
                category: "haram"
              }
              abc.push(rr);  
            }

           
          });  
        } 
    })
  })
```

});

I am pushing values into abc array after searching them using findOne. How do I send the array as res.json since it is an asynchronous function.

Comment: You have to wait for all the promises to finish, such as with `Promise.all`

Comment: Do you mean send it as a response?  Have you tried res.json({});

Comment: @Taplar how do i do this? I am using callbacks in my function

Comment: @themagicbean Yes as a response. But it is in a asynchronous function it is coming as empty.

Comment: @Taplar yes this is mongoose. I pasted the whole code but stackoverflow didn't let me so i had to remove some of it.

Comment: K, I've added that tag to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.post('/ingredients', (req, res) => {
    var abc = [];
    var a = data.toString().split("\r\n");
    var arr = a.toString().split(",");
    var promises = [];

    arr.forEach(function (i, e) {
        if (i != "\r" && i != "\n" && i != "" && i != " ") {
            var v = i.trim().toLowerCase();

            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Ingredient.findOne({ name: v }, (err, us) => {
                    if (us) {
                        var rr = {
                            name: us.name,
                            category: "haram"
                        }
                        abc.push(rr);
                    }
                    resolve();
                });
            }))
        }
    })

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        res.json(abc);
    })
});
```

This should fix your problem. Basically you create an array of promises and then wait for all promises to be resolved. A more elegant solution would be to use async/await approach.